# Setting multiple user data values at once in Xcode Scene Editor

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, sceneeditor

I'm assigning user data values for many sprites in Xcode's SpriteKit Scene Editor. It's time-consuming and more difficult to set the user data for one sprite at a time. I'm wondering if there is a way to select multiple sprites in the editor and assign a user data value to all of them at once.

[image]

I tried doing this, but user data only gets set for the first sprite selected. Unfortunately, setting user data in code is not an option in this situation. Does anyone know a better way to do this in the editor? My research suggests not, but I'm wondering if I may have overlooked something.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is setting it in code not an option? Iterating over a set of sprites and setting a property in `didMoveToView` seems pretty trivial, and I can’t imagine a situation in hitch that wouldn’t work.

Comment: you can't multi set at once unfortunately, apple has not designed it yet.  @SteveIves because it is code smell, no point in cluttering code with useless data sets when you can set it up as part of the design.

Comment: Did you try setting up one dot the way you like it, then copy and paste that finished dot to create duplicates?  Your other option is to make dot a separate SCN file, and use SKReferenceNodes to be able make your life easier

Comment: I was afraid the answer would be simply, "that's not possible yet". The code approach is not practical in this situation as the userData config decision for each sprite is made one at a time at the design level for 1000+ sprites spread across 100 scene files. @Knight0fDragon I considered duplicates and that would have worked at the beginning, but positions are already set; now I am going back to set userData and duplicating a sprite would ruin the set-up work already done for sprite positions. I've not heard about your second approach but it's intriguing. I'll look into it when I get a chance.

Comment: FYI: This is also a problem in the Scene Kit Editor